# understanding java if clause syntax

Tags: java

I was going through the following code, and I do not understand what `sum-in` means in this clause:

```
if (sum-in == largest)
```

Here is the context of that line:

```
public static String ArrayAdditionI(int[] arr) {
    // find max
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    int largest = arr[arr.length - 1];

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    java.util.List<Integer> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }

    if (largest == sum) return "true";

    for (Integer in : list) {
        if (sum-in == largest){
            return "true";
        }
    }
    return "false";
  }
```

Comment: `sum` minus `in`. That's why we *should* have space there: `if(sum - in = largest)`

Comment: `in` is an integer. You're doing a substraction

Comment: There should be a close reason for that...

Comment: Good example of why it's recommended to use spaces...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP didn't know that "-" is the minus sign.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think it's more that the fact the variable was named `in` locked his mind into trying to interpreting it as an operator.

Comment: @dystroy Indeed. Naming the variable `in` just because you cannot name it `int` is a hurtful idea.

Answer (score 3):

Its subtraction. It could be rewritten as

```
if ( (sum - in) == largest)
```

**Edit:** I realize that this is simply a result of variable naming rules for Java. If you scroll to the bottom of this page, you will see the [naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). TL;DR: The only symbols allowed in a variable name are alphanumeric characters, the underscore '_', and the dollar sighn '$' which isn't really used much.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a minus sign. For subtraction. Sum minus in. In subtracted from sum.

More generally, you should use a print statement or a debugger to find out more information when you have questions like these.

"Hey I'm not sure what that's doing, maybe I should try printing it out:"

```
System.out.println(sum);
System.out.println(in);
System.out.println(sum-in);
System.out.println(largest);
System.out.println(sum-in == largest);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a consolidation of this:

```
int temp = sum - in;
if (temp == largest){
...
```